# SQL Selecting From One Table With Multiple Where Clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

Searching high and low for an answer to this one and having no luck. I'm sure it can't be as complicated as I think it is.

I have one table with titles and codes. The codes are unique and can have more than one titlecode. 
I want to be able to select those titles that have codes I list.

```
 Titles                        Codes
 -----------------------------------
 Book1                         001
 Book2                         010
 Book2                         020
 Book2                         021
 Book3                         030
 Book3                         040
```

So I want to be able to return Titles that have codes 020 and 021. Or whatever I list. 
In this case it would just return Book2 as that Title has those two codes.

I initially tried

```
 SELECT Titles FROM table WHERE Codes = 020 AND Codes = 021
```

but that returned zero results and I could see why. No row contains more than one Codes entry

```
 SELECT Titles FROM table WHERE Codes = 020 OR Codes = 021
```

returns Titles that are either. 
So I've been trying to use GROUP BY and also a subquery to try and get it but having no luck. 
Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance

Comment: SELECT m FROM my_table WHERE x IN (a,b,c) GROUP BY m HAVING COUNT(*) = n;  -- where n is the number of items in IN()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the data you're looking for you will need to use a self-join on your table:

```
SELECT * FROM table t1
JOIN table t2
ON t1.Title = t2.Title
WHERE t1.Codes = '020'
AND t2.Codes = '021'
```

Comment: Perfect! A self join! Thank you Brian, that's great.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT Titles
FROM table
GROUP BY Titles
HAVING SUM(Codes = '020') > 0 AND SUM(Codes = '021') > 0;
```

Comment: Huh, that's clever, but may not scale well as you increase the number of factors to be matched.

Comment: For performance, you can add `where Codes in ('020', '021')` before the `group by`.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. This one didn't seem to work though. Brian's self-join seems to do the trick though. Cheers

Comment: @user3683463 . . . How did this not work?  I've used similar constructs many, many times.