# MySQL select query ANDed multiple condition of same column

Tags: mysql

I have the below test table with the following rows in the table.

```
table: test_set(id (pk), pid int, fc int, fl int)

pid      fc    fl
1        7     30
1        8     31
1        9     35
2        7     39
2        8     40
```

Now if I run

```
SELECT pid FROM test_set WHERE fl=30 OR fl=35 GROUP BY pid;
#Result :
pid
---
1
```

As expected but if I want to run

```
SELECT pid FROM test_set WHERE fl=30 AND fl=35 GROUP BY pid;
#Result :
result set (0) # Nothing matched!
```

This is too as expected but I want to go beyond expectation here. My logic here is that **fl=30** and **fl=35** both have **pid=1** in common i.e. when they are intersected they yeilds pid=1

So to be specific I need the result of multiple values of fl column that have one or more **pid** in common.

I have already read this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620069/mysql-select-query-with-multiple-conditions-of-same-column) and commented there too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Selecting From One Table With Multiple Where Clauses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455195/sql-selecting-from-one-table-with-multiple-where-clauses)

Comment: @Brian I have read that. But what if there are more **fl** in condition? How many self join then? And in real application I can't rewrite join queries time and again. It's normally pre-written (of course by me) in business logic as a reusable query method.(You know that, right ?)

Comment: Did you try the other answer (using HAVING clause instead of self join)?

Comment: @rlanvin No sir I did not. I am looking for some normalized solution. For example using set methods (as in maths) I want the WHERE condition to be normalized. I don't want to solve it in a rigid way. Please never mind in my dogmatism.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SELECT pid, COUNT(DISTINCT fl) AS count, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fl) list
FROM test_set
GROUP BY pid HAVING count > 1;
```

?

Output:

```
+------+-----------+------------------+
| pid  | count     | list             |
+------+-----------+------------------+
|    1 |         3 | 30,31,35         |
|    2 |         2 | 39,40            |
+------+-----------+------------------+
```

Given two `fl` values:

```
SELECT pid, COUNT(DISTINCT fl) AS count
FROM test_set
WHERE fl IN (30, 35)
GROUP BY pid HAVING count = 2;
```

Output:

```
+------+-------+
| pid  | count |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     2 |
+------+-------+
```

Given three `fl` values:

```
SELECT pid, COUNT(DISTINCT fl) AS count
FROM test_set
WHERE fl IN (30, 31, 35)
GROUP BY pid HAVING count = 3;
```

Output:

```
+------+-------+
| pid  | count |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     3 |
+------+-------+
```

It's good to have indexes on `pid` and `fl`.

Comment: It should give pid =1 when fl=30 and fl=35 are ANDed? Can you please make that query out?

Comment: What if there are more **fl** ? How come the self join work then? I mean how many times do I write self join?